# Python - How to repeatedly concatenate a string into a larger string

Tags: python, string

So I have a script which reaches out to an API and pulls a bunch of host names. For example, look at the 5 hosts below. (For reference, typical return is anywhere from a few hundred to a few thousand host names,)

```
  b4aa2exxxbf6e95a3225,
  9a851xxx2a4fee07s439c,
  e17b87exxx8250dc949,
  3252dbxxxcabd8a568b3,
  6c3029c212ae4xxx31d06,
```

But here's my problem. When these host names are returned to me, they are formatted as one big string. For every hostname I need to remove the `","` and concatenate the following string where the comma used to be,
`&ids=`,  so that I can pass this string along as a parameter to another API endpoint.

If anyone knows a simple way to get this done, I would love some help!

Comment: look into using `split` to jam those all into a `list` then you can manipulate it how you wish

Comment: Look at the `.split()` and `.join()` methods of strings.

Comment: I will take a look at that right now!

Comment: This question needs the input data (okay), the according output data (missing) and the code you have tried (missing). Just as a hint, there is documentation on strings and you can also use `help(x)` or `dir(x)` to get an idea what `x` can do and that also works for strings.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski this chopped the strings up by character and populated a list where each entry is one character.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the `replace` method.

```py
baseString = 'b4aa2exxxbf6e95a3225,9a851xxx2a4fee07s439c,e17b87exxx8250dc949,3252dbxxxcabd8a568b3,6c3029c212ae4xxx31d06,'
newString = baseString.replace(',', '&ids=')
```

if you have one too much comma at the end, simply remove the last character from the string.

Comment: That worked! But there was a bit of an oversight on my part - there is a new line character between every entry. I'm assuming I can use the same method to replace all ```\n``` with ```''```?

Comment: you can. you could also just `replace(',\n', '&ids=')`